# visualizing LDA model using pyLDAvis

Tags: gensim, topic-modeling, pyldavis

I'm running jupyter notebook in vscode.
I have build my LDA model using gensim but when I want to visualize it, it shows nothing.

my code is:

```
import pyLDAvis 
import pyLDAvis.gensim_models

pyLDAvis.enable_notebook(local=True)
vis = pyLDAvis.gensim_models.prepare(lda_model, corpus, id2word)

vis
```

I tried display method of pyLDAvis it didn't work neither

I'm expecting some plots and graphs like this [address](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/topic-modeling-gensim-python/#15visualizethetopicskeywords)

Answer (score 0):

I found some answer for it. It still wont work on jupyter extension of VScode but on jupyterlab on browser it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply a display method on the prepared data for the visualization to show up.
Try this:

```
import pyLDAvis 
import pyLDAvis.gensim_models

pyLDAvis.enable_notebook(local=True)
vis = pyLDAvis.gensim_models.prepare(lda_model, corpus, id2word)

pyLDAvis.display(vis)
```